# Map local (like Charles Proxy or Proxyman) a iframe url

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, http-proxy

There is this page; https://previewer.weborama.nl/preview/Gg28.
This page is placing a iframe with the url;
//api.warm.weborama.nl/files/advertiser/5580/3073/16217/15899/interscroller.html?....

I want to use my local interscroller.html file instead of this url.

I've tried [Charlesproxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/):

[image]

and I tried [Proxyman](https://proxyman.io/):

[image]

But without results. I also played around with the path a bit, but without luck. As you can see, the url has some parameters that will change with every refresh. That's why I'm using `*` at the end of the url.

Is it even possible to Map Local a iframe url?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Because the Iframe was using this url; //api.warm.weborama.nl/files/advertiser/5580/3073/16217/15899/interscroller.html?... I was using this url to proxy.

Proxyman support told me that `//` is not a valid protocol and that I should use `https` instead.

[image]

Now it's working like a charm!